# The Publication tcm:0-7-1 does not have a stub Folder configured in a Parent Publication

Tags: 2013-sp1, content-manager, ecl

I have Tridion 2013 SP1 running on a fresh SQL Server DB.  I created 4 publications and all was fine:
[image]

Then I created a 5th publication at level 03 inheriting from a global content publication at level 2.  All went fine as well.  Here is the updated Blueprint:

[image]

Now, when I try to expand the new publication, I get this error:
[image]

Here is the stacktrace from the "Show Details" of the error dialog:

> The Publication tcm:0-7-1 does not have a stub Folder configured in a Parent Publication.
>    at
>   Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.DomainModel.StubSchema.GetStubSchemaId(MountPointConfiguration
>   mountPointConfiguration, Int32 publicationId, UserContext userContext)
>   at
>   Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.DomainModel.UserContext.ExecutePrivileged[T](String
>   userName, Func`1 privilegedCode) at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator`2.MoveNext() at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.d__81`1.MoveNext() at
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source) at
>   Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.DomainModel.UserContext.InitializeMountPoints(IEnumerable`1
>   eclUris) at
>   Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.DomainModel.UserContext.GetMountPoints(Int32
>   publicationId) at
>   Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.Service.EclService2012.GetList(String
>   parentItemId, Int32 pageIndex, EclItemTypes itemTypes, IEnumerable`1
>   basedOnSchema) at SyncInvokeGetList(Object , Object[] , Object[] ) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object
>   instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs) at
>   Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.Service.TransactionSupportInvoker.Invoke(Object
>   instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean
>   isOperationContextSet)

I scanned the existing ECL related Q&A's on this forum and also did some Googling around blogs, but couldn't find anything of hint.  Any ideas on where to look next or why this problem arose?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since an ECL Provider(s) was configured on the system previously, the error states that there are some remnants of this in the CME. According to the SDL Documentation (http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-948FBBE8-6127-4943-981F-BB2FDF87C2C6):

> Multimedia Components are generated for external multimedia in the
>   Stub Folder configured in ExternalContentLibrary.xml.

Check that the publication ID of the stub folder is not the same as of the new publication that got added:

```
    <MountPoint type="FilesystemProvider" version="*" id="fs" rootItemName="Filesystem">
        <StubFolders>
            <StubFolder id="tcm:7-26-2" />
        </StubFolders>
        <PrivilegedUserName>TRIDION\Admin</PrivilegedUserName>
        <FilesystemPath xmlns="filesystem-ns">C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Resources</FilesystemPath>
    </MountPoint>

    <MountPoint type="FlickrProvider" version="*" id="ftp" rootItemName="Flickr">
        <StubFolders>
            <StubFolder id="tcm:7-1020-2" />
        </StubFolders>
        <PrivilegedUserName>TRIDION\Admin</PrivilegedUserName> 
        <FlickrApiKey xmlns="http://flickr.com/services/api">5ca72e7834b2b05ae9ea367df7f73fa8</FlickrApiKey>
        <FlickrNSID xmlns="http://flickr.com/services/api">120845494@N04</FlickrNSID>
    </MountPoint>
```

Sure enough, I had an ECL connector installed on an my existing CME, and after pointing to a different database, once the publication with the same ID got added, that publication crapped out.  Removing the config from the ExternalContentLibrary.xml solved it for me.

Hope this helps the next person. Cheers!

Comment: Good find, should be helpful. But can you replace that screenshot of XML with the actual XML?

Comment: done and done my good man